# PHP: setting cookies - the old values isn't replaced for some reason

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a script where I set 2 cookies:

```
$month = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
setcookie('id', $id, $month, '/');
setcookie('auth', $auth, $month, '/');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
print('<html><body>...etc....');
```

This does work well, but: some users have several id's, depending on from which page (social network) they access my script through an iframe.

A user having several id's is not a problem. But my problem is that when I ask that person to look at his cookies, he'll report that there are several cookies called **id** and **auth**. And I can reproduce it myself too.

And I was actually expecting there always to be just 1 **id** and 1 **auth** cookie.

What can I do here?

Doesn't calling **setcookie('id', ...)** with a new value replace the old value?

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: Are all those multiple cookies your seeing actually from the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are based on a KV Scheme (Key=Value) concept and the Key's act as unique identifiers.

The three primary effectors of `setcookie` are

- CREATE

  - Create a cookie with `setcookie("id","value")`
- READ

  - Read a cookie with `$_COOKIE["id"]`
- UPDATE

  - Update a cookie with `setcookie("id","new value")`
- DELETE

  - Delete by setting the expiration in the past `setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 10);`

so yes your correct in your question, you should have a look at other factors that may deter the cookie states.